# How to fetch joined tables data into bean with inner-beans using JDBCDaoSupport in Spring

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

I have parent and child tables.

I have created a bean of Parent class to hold parent table data and as a contentment in Parent Class I have created List/Map to hold Child table data.

I want to fetch this data using joins.

Can I accomplish this using JDBCDaoSupport Class in spring or intervation of Hibernate / JPA is necessory.

Thanks in advance.